# graphql angular получить запись по id

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, graphql, apollo-client

Я получаю через graphql `ship` по `id` с [api spacex](https://api.spacex.land/graphql/), вот запрос, который можно вбить на сайте:

```
{
  ships(find: {id: "GOMSTREE"}) {
    home_port
    missions {
      name
    }
    type
    year_built
    id
  }
}
```

Я из [компонента](https://github.com/mihinov/rocket-app/blob/main/src/app/ship-details/ship-details.component.ts) вызываю метод из своего [сервиса](https://github.com/mihinov/rocket-app/blob/main/src/app/ship-details/ship-details.service.ts), вот [компонент](https://github.com/mihinov/rocket-app/blob/main/src/app/ship-details/ship-details.component.ts):

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ShipDetailsService } from './ship-details.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ship-details',
  templateUrl: './ship-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ship-details.component.scss']
})
export class ShipDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subs: Subscription;
  constructor(private shipDetailsService: ShipDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subs = this.shipDetailsService.getShipById('GOMSTREE').subscribe(item => {
      console.log(item);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subs.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

А вот [сервис](https://github.com/mihinov/rocket-app/blob/main/src/app/ship-details/ship-details.service.ts):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Ship } from '../shared/interfaces';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo, gql } from 'apollo-angular';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ShipDetailsService {
  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  getShipById(id: string): Observable<Ship[]> {
    const query = gql`
      query getShipById($findStr: String) {
        ships {
          find: {
            id: $findStr
          }
          id
          home_port
          missions {
            name
          }
          type
          year_built
        }
      }
    `;

    return this.apollo.watchQuery<Ship[]>({
      query,
      variables: {
        findStr: id
      }
    }).valueChanges.pipe(map(item => item.data));
  }
}
```

Но в итоге я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю, возможно, я неправильно написал graphql запрос, наверное. Подскажите, что не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сервисе нужно было query запрос по другому написать, вот так:

```
query getShipById($findStr: ID!) {
  ships(find: {id: $findStr}) {
    id
    home_port
    missions {
      name
    }
    type
    year_built
  }
}
```